# Add the quantity of items of java string

Tags: java, string, split

I have a list. I want to add up the quantities of ingredients.
Let say, we have `List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1 kg chicken", "1 kg olive oil", "250g chicken", "250 g chicken");`

code

```
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1 kg chicken", "1 kg olive oil", "250g chicken", "250 g chicken");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
                if (meatList.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase((list.get(j))))
               //here to code

                    int quanity1 = Integer.valueOf(list.get(i).split(" ").toString());
                    int quanity2 = Integer.valueOf(list.get(j).split(" ").toString());

                    int qty = quanity1 + quanity2;

            }
        }
```

> **Required Output**: 1 kg olive oil, 1.5 kg chicken

Meanwhile, it should consider the "chicken" on both ingredients and then sum their quantities.

Comment: Is meatList the same as list?

Comment: @NomadMaker yes it same. Please check the update question

Comment: Dig you mean to have both 250g and 250 g?

Comment: @NomadMaker yes I have both . Free text by user

Comment: I would suggest breaking the info out of Strings and put it into a class object that can track the amount and the type of ingredient as two separate values. That said, if you want to work with Strings for this you can accomplish specific value grabbing with the `.contains("chicken")` to identify which lines contain that ingredient followed by using the regex [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) `\\n+g` and `\\n+kg` to grab the number from the String as well as the measurement size.

Comment: @TimHunter Please provide me the answer. I am unable to do, I would be much thankful to you for this.

Comment: Nope. I have more important things to do then write your code for you. An outline of a possible approach and a reference to a useful library tool is all you're getting from me.

Comment: Is this homework with some well defined limitations or is it a real application? Extracting data from free text is very complicated and it would be much easier if the list contained a class with member variables for ingredient, quantity etc. Simple example, parsing your list would be much harder if we also add the ingredient chicken stock.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Sir this is an real app. I have a two list .
i) One list has all the possible units (like g,kg,ml,l etc)
ii) 2nd list for the names of the ingredients like (mutton,chicken,beef)

Comment: If this is a real app then I would suggest you change the part where you get input from the user so quantity, measurement and ingredient are separate values rather than one string.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sir I already have some dataset which I supposed to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be complicated to cover all possibilities of entered text but here is a solution to start with using reg ex matching

The regular expression will try to match first digits (quantity) followed by 0 or more spaces and then some letters (weight etc) space and then the rest of the string is assume to be the ingredient.

```
String regex = "^(\\d+)\\s*(\\w*)\\s*(.*)$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String string : list) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        Integer quantity = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1).trim());
        String measurement = matcher.group(2).trim();
        String ingredient = matcher.group(3).trim();

        System.out.printf("Quantity: %d, measurement: %s, ingredient: %s\n", quantity, measurement, ingredient);
    }
}
```

Using the list "1 kg chicken", "1 kg olive oil", "250g chicken", "250 g chicken" this outputs

> Quantity: 1, measurement: kg, ingredient: chicken
>   Quantity: 1, measurement: kg, ingredient: olive oil
>   Quantity: 250, measurement: g, ingredient: chicken
>   Quantity: 250, measurement: g, ingredient: chicken

---

*Update*

If you want to handle measurements like 1/2 or 0.5 then the reg ex needs to be modified to

```
String regex = "^([\\d/.]+)\\s*(\\w*)\\s*(.*)$";
```

but be aware that you can no longer convert the value of the first match to an integer, 0.5 can be converted to a double but 1/2 needs to be handled manually.

Comment: sir thanks for the answer. Your answer is working for me. Could you please add a little bit update in Regex for the use case "'1/2 cup Chicken Broth"

Comment: @Lily I have made an update to my answer but please respect that you can't continue to add to your question. If you want to use reg ex matching then you also need to research it so that you understand and improve the code yourself

Comment: Thank you, sir. I do understand.